# Subclass of PyTorch DataLoader for changing batch output

Tags: pytorch, dataset, pytorch-dataloader

I'm interested in a way of applying a transform to a batch generated by a `PyTorch` `DataLoader` class. My minimal example is something like this:

```
class CustomLoader(torch.utils.data.DataLoader):
    def __iter__(self):
        result = super().__iter__()
        return some_function(result)
```

But this errors since the `DataLoader.__iter()__` returns `_MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter` or `_SingleProcessingDataLoaderIter`. Weirdly though, directly returning the output does return a `Tensor`, so any explanation there would be greatly appreciated!

I understand that in general, transform to data should be done in the subclassed `Dataset` class. However, in my case the data is tabular and the transform is via numpy, and doing it on a sample-wise basis is much slower (5x) than doing it on an entire batch, since surely these operations are vectorized under the hood.

I know I can do something simple like

```
for X, y in loader:
    X = some_function(X)
```

But I'd also like to use the DataLoader with `pytorch-lightning`, so this isn't an option.

What is the proper way to subclass PyTorch Dataloaders?

Comment: But why doing `X = some_function(X)` in  `training_step` method of `pl.LightningModule` is impossible? It's simple as you wrote and it's works fine with default DataLoader.

Comment: @draw Right, I should clarify more. In my case, the other arguments to `some_function` are dependent on a attribute of the underlying `Dataset`. Therefore, if I try to change the batch in `training_step` I won't have the info needed to do so.

Answer (score 0):

`__iter__()` is a generator. You will need to yield the result instead of returning it. You can read more about generators [here](https://www.guru99.com/python-yield-return-generator.html)

Regarding your problem to apply a transform to a batch, you can create a custom Dataset instead of DataLoader and then apply the transforms.

```
class MyDataset(Dataset):
   def __init__(self, transforms=None):
      super().__init__()
      self.data = ...  # define your data here
      self.transforms = transforms

   def __getitem__(self, idx):
      x = self.data[idx]
      if self.transforms: x = self.transforms(x)
      return x

# use your `MyDataset` class for creating your dataloader
dataloader = DataLoader(MyDataset(transforms = CustomTransforms(), batch_size=4)
```

You can use this dataloader with PyTorch Lightning Trainer as well.

If you are using PyTorch Lightning, I would suggest you to join our [Slack channel](https://join.slack.com/t/pytorch-lightning/shared_invite/zt-12iz3cds1-uyyyBYJLiaL2bqVmMN7n%7EA) and ask questions on [Github Discussions](https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/discussions) as well.

Thanks :)

EDIT: (Add transforms to Batch)

If you are using PyTorch Lightning then I would recommend to use LightningDataModule which provides `on_before_batch_transfer` hook that can be used to apply transforms on a batch ;)

Here is an example:

```py
def on_before_batch_transfer(self, batch, dataloader_idx):
    batch['x'] = transforms(batch['x'])
    return batch
```

Checkout [the documentation for more](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extensions/datamodules.html#on-before-batch-transfer)

Comment: Thank you! I understand that you can apply transforms to the dataset, but in my case that slows down the DataLoader considerably, since applying the transform batch-wise is 5x faster than sample-wise.

Comment: If you are using PyTorch Lightning then I would recommend to use LightningDataModule which provides `on_before_batch_transfer` hook that can be used to apply transforms on a batch ;)

Here is an example:

```python
def on_before_batch_transfer(self, batch, dataloader_idx):
    batch['x'] = transforms(batch['x'])
    return batch
```

Checkout [the documentation for more](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extensions/datamodules.html#on-before-batch-transfer)